# PMD xpath rule to warn about the use of equals() on BigDecimal

Tags: pmd

Could someone suggest a PMD xpath rule to warn that calling the `equals()` method of `java.math.BigDecimal` will check for both value and scale which usually (unless for some engineering type apps) might be a mistake. Since `1.0` not equals `1.00`, one should use `compareTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks rather complicated with PMD but [FindBugs already has a rule for this](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#MDM_BIGDECIMAL_EQUALS).

Comment: No, it doesn't. Seems the rule is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

This will be difficult with XPath as the violation is on the method invocation but you need information about the type of the object. A Java based PMD rule might the way to go.